# loop through multidimensional array in php and do mysql insert (stock data)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a multidemensional array that I wish to loop threw and do a mysql database insert for the values in the array.

The array values I need to insert into a sql query are :

```
candles[0][complete], candles[0][volume], candles[0][mid][h], candles[0][mid][l], candles[0][mid][c]  
candles[1][complete], candles[1][volume], candles[1][mid][h], candles[1][mid][l], candles[1][mid][c] 
candles[2][complete], candles[2][volume], candles[2][mid][h], candles[2][mid][l], candles[2][mid][c]
```

The array:

```
$get_instruments_candles = Array
(
    [instrument] => EUR_USD
    [granularity] => H4
    [candles] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [complete] => 1
                    [volume] => 4491
                    [time] => 2009-01-01T22:00:00.000000000Z
                    [bid] => Array
                        (
                            [o] => 1.40390
                            [h] => 1.40515
                            [l] => 1.39445
                            [c] => 1.39540  
                        )

                    [mid] => Array
                        (
                            [o] => 1.40440
                            [h] => 1.40565
                            [l] => 1.39470
                            [c] => 1.39565
                        )

                    [ask] => Array
                        (
                            [o] => 1.40490
                            [h] => 1.40615
                            [l] => 1.39495
                            [c] => 1.39590
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [complete] => 1
                    [volume] => 6866
                    [time] => 2009-01-02T02:00:00.000000000Z
                    [bid] => Array
                        (
                            [o] => 1.39545
                            [h] => 1.39690
                            [l] => 1.38447
                            [c] => 1.38641
                        )

                    [mid] => Array
                        (
                            [o] => 1.39570
                            [h] => 1.39715
                            [l] => 1.38472
                            [c] => 1.38666
                        )

                    [ask] => Array
                        (
                            [o] => 1.39595
                            [h] => 1.39740
                            [l] => 1.38497
                            [c] => 1.38691
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [complete] => 1
                    [volume] => 12529
                    [time] => 2009-01-02T06:00:00.000000000Z
                    [bid] => Array
                        (
                            [o] => 1.38635
                            [h] => 1.39679
                            [l] => 1.38391
                            [c] => 1.39471
                        )

                    [mid] => Array
                        (
                            [o] => 1.38660
                            [h] => 1.39688
                            [l] => 1.38400
                            [c] => 1.39480
                        )

                    [ask] => Array
                        (
                            [o] => 1.38685
                            [h] => 1.39697
                            [l] => 1.38409
                            [c] => 1.39489
                        )

                )

        )

 )
```

This array can be made up of upto 5000 candle[] values, so I need to find the best way to do a foreach or while loop in php to run threw the array values and do a MySQL insert

```
// connect to mysql database

// Do a loop to create and insert the values into database    

// Create sql Query to insert. [0] would be changed to arrays value 0,1,2,3,etc

$sql = "INSERT INTO table (complete, volume, high, low, close) 
VALUES ('{candles[0][complete]}','{candles[0][volume]}','{candles[0][mid][h]}','{candles[0][mid][l]}','{candles[0][mid][c]}')";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `foreach` loop and then refer to the current element of the loop. It would be best to use a prepared statement. Here's the PDO version:

```
$stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO table (complete, volume, high, low, close) 
                        VALUES (:complete, :volume, :high, :low, :close)";
$stmt->bindParam(':complete', $complete);
$stmt->bindParam(':volumn', $volume);
$stmt->bindParam(':high', $high);
$stmt->bindParam(':low', $low);
$stmt->bindParam(':close', $close);

foreach ($get_instrument_candles['candles'] as $candle) {
    $complete = $candle['complete'];
    $volume = $candle['volume'];
    $high = $candle['mid']['h'];
    $low = $candle['mid']['l'];
    $close = $candle['mid']['c'];
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

The mysqli version would look like:

```
$complete = $volume = $high = $low = $close = null;
$stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO table (complete, volume, high, low, close) 
                        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt->bind_param("iiiii", $complete, $volume, $high, $low, $close);
```

The `foreach` loop is the same as for PDO.

Comment: Maybe if you align the placeholder names with the structure of the associative array you can just `execute()` against that directly.

Comment: @tadman It looks like the response from a public API, so he probably doesn't have much control over the structure.

Comment: True enough, though it would be nice if that could be depended on.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, this does slove the problem for acceesing the array

Answer (score 1):

Another approach (assuming you trust the input data) would be to generate a single, large `INSERT` query. The longest query size (set by [`max_allowed_packet`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet), defaulting to 4MB for MySQL < 8.0.2) should be more than sufficient to allow for inserting data for 5000 candles. So the code would look like:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (complete, volume, high, low, close) VALUES ";
foreach ($get_instrument_candles['candles'] as $candle) {
   $sql .= "({$candle['complete']}, {$candle['volume']}, {$candle['mid']['h']}, {$candle['mid']['l']}, {$candle['mid']['c']}),";
}
// strip the trailing comma
$sql = substr($sql, 0, -1);
```

If you can't be certain the input data is safe, @Barmar's approach of a prepared statement is the way to go.

Comment: the api array is safe so doing a insert like you mention is a good option, I have to do a few checks if the data is already stored, then simply append as you mention

Comment: If you have a unique key on the data then you could just use an `INSERT IGNORE` and not worry about checking whether it is already stored.